# Math puzzle I have been stuck on

Tags: puzzle

Have had this math puzzle that I have been unable to solve for a while.

Each leter is a number between 1-9. No letter uses the same number twice (aka if B is 3 D can't be 3 also). The ? mark represents an unknown letter (as in it could be any letter).

$$A + B + C + D = EF$$
$$G + F + E + H = CJ$$
$$B + G + J = \;?D$$

Comment: Does $EF$ mean $E$ is the ten's digit and $F$ is the one's digit or is it a product?

Comment: Yes it does mean that ones

Comment: We know that
$$
EF=A+B+C+D\le 9+8+7+6=30
$$
Hence $E\in\{1,2\}$, by the same method we find $C\in\{1,2\}$. Which means that $\{E,C\}=\{1,2\}$

Comment: Just use a constraint solver. a=4 b=6 c=2 d=7 e=1 f=9 g=8 h=5 j=3, a=8 b=5 c=2 d=4 e=1 f=9 g=6 h=7 j=3, a=7 b=6 c=2 d=4 e=1 f=9 g=5 h=8 j=3, a=9 b=5 c=1 d=8 e=2 f=3 g=7 h=4 j=6.

Comment: @simonzack I also get this set of ans. Is it the only one?

Comment: @hkmather802 I've added all solutions.

Comment: The problem is to prove that there is only one solution, if I'm not wrong.

Comment: @k1.M you can check that all of mine work, there are 4 different solutions.

Comment: So maybe this is not a nice question...

Comment: Is there an easy way to see that $?$ is always going to be $1$?